# How do I log all Cloudfront viewer requests with country/device info when that info is only available on cache misses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm running into a certain problem with Cloudfront. I'd like to have it so that all viewer requests to Cloudfront get logged alongside with information about the viewer request, like country and device details.

On cache misses, when Cloudfront has to make an origin request, it's trivial because you can easily configure Cloudfront to send headers like `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` and `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` along with that origin request. However, I have no idea how to access that information on cache *hits* (since no origin request is made then) given what's available in the viewer request/viewer response.

The best I can get seems to be in the Cloudfront logs, where `x-edge-location` gives me a rough idea of the location of each request, but that really doesn't have the desired granularity I'm looking for, and ideally I wouldn't have to go to a third party for IP lookups or anything. Is there any way to get the desired logging information even for requests that don't go to the origin? Thanks!

Comment: Is the CloudFront Viewers Report what you are looking for? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/viewers-reports.html

Comment: This looks amazing! But the data seems to be completely agnostic to the requested endpoint, which is a problem :/

Comment: What's wrong with CF logs? You have to do a bit of decoding. You can find mapping tables online to translate edge location codes into countries (ex. https://www.feitsui.com/en/article/3) and I remember decoding the device string with a Python library.

Comment: They're definitely useful, but even some fairly big countries are missing: Russia is a notable example

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. AWS is not operating in Russia so you won't find any region or POP. If you want the location of the client you have indeed to decode the IP. You have good quality databases out there that you can download to do the decoding locally. I used ip2location in the past.